# my "token-signature" in aws iot test-invoke-authorizer always mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I had try to use AWS IoT Core Authorizer with AWS Lamda Function follow this guide. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/config-custom-auth.html
and this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-auth-tutorial.html

I can create Lamda Function and Authorizer like that guide. But I had always got this Error : `"An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the TestInvokeAuthorizer operation: Token signature mismatch for authorizer my-new-authorizer1"` when I try to test it by test-invoke-authorizer.
I guess I maybe do some mistake on key-generate or signature-generate by OpenSSL.
So I try to validate them for check the compatible of them and It's compatible.

And now, I have no idea what I do mistake. Does anyone suggest me what should I do

Thank You for your time.